# Is there a way to have a method accept blocks with different signatures?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, objective-c-blocks

I have this:

```
typedef void (^resultMail)(MFMailComposeViewController *controller, MFMailComposeResult result);
typedef void (^resultMessage)(MFMessageComposeViewController *controller, MessageComposeResult result);
```

and I have this:

```
- (void)shareMailWithImage:(UIImage *)image
     onCompletion:(resultMail)result;
```

and

```
- (void)shareMessageWithImage:(UIImage *)image
     onCompletion:(resultMessage)result;
```

I would like to unify both methods with something like this

```
- (void)shareType:(typeShare)type withImage:(UIImage*)image onCompletion:...
```

`typeShare` will be a `typedef` like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, typeShare) 
{
  kTypeMail = 100,
  kTypeMessage,
};
```

My problem is the `onCompletion` block. Each of the previous methods had one specific block signature.

Is it possible to unify that? I mean to create one method that can use any signature for that block as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about changing your block to accept parameters of the respective superclasses?

```
typedef void (^result)(UINavigationController *controller, NSInteger result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just make the parameters more generic..

```
typedef void (^newResult)(id controller, NSInteger result);

- (void)shareType:(typeShare)type withImage:(UIImage*)image onCompletion:(newResult)result;
```

This way you can do with result block whatever you want. Both of your blocks pass in a controller and a typedef integer as a result.